# Slicing a List + Converting a Nested List into a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of items, which has a name and item description in the same string.
I was able to slice them and separate into item names and item description, however when items do not have description, how can I create an empty description for its item name?

```
new_lst=[]
lst = [
    'Macbook Air - 13inch Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max Pro 65GB Model',
    'Airpod2'
    ]

for item in lst:
    new_lst.append(str(item).split('-', 1))

print(new_lst)
```

My output looks like this

```
[['Macbook Air ', ' 13inch Model'], ['Iphone13 ', ' Max Pro 65GB Model'], ['Airpod2']]
```

but I want them looks like this

```
[['Macbook Air ', ' 13inch Model'], ['Iphone13 ', ' Max Pro 65GB Model'], ['Airpod2','']]
```

eventually my goals is to convert a nested list into a dictionary.
So I would like to use item names as keys and descriptions as its values like below

```
[{'Macbook Air ':' 13inch Model'}, {'Iphone13 ':' Max Pro 65GB Model'}, {'Airpod2':''}]
```

Comment: Question - is it fine to take last item as this output - `Airport, []`

Comment: I think so as long as I can make a key and an empty value like last output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this what you're looking for?  Try this out and ask question, if any.

Note - the output is **One** dictionary with all items.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    'Macbook Air - 13inch Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max Pro 65GB Model',
    'Airpod2'
    ]
dc = defaultdict(str)

for item in lst:
    x, *y = item.split('-')
    dc[x] = y
    
print(dc)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'Macbook Air ': [' 13inch Model'], 'Iphone13 ': [' Max Pro 65GB Model'], 'Airpod2': []})
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a great usecase for the [`string.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=string%20partition#str.partition) method:

```py
new_lst=[]
lst = [
    'Macbook Air - 13inch Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max Pro 65GB Model',
    'Airpod2'
]

for item in lst:
    product, _, desc = str(item).partition('-')
    new_lst.append([product, desc])

print(new_lst)
# [['Macbook Air ', ' 13inch Model'], ['Iphone13 ', ' Max Pro 65GB Model'], ['Airpod2', '']]
```

string.partition is behaviorally the exact same as `string.split(..., 1)` except that string.partition is always guaranteed to return a tuple of 3 items (empty strings if no successful split could be performed).

---

If you want a dictionary output, you can do the same but just store your results directly into a dictionary:

```py
lst = [
    'Macbook Air - 13inch Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max Pro 65GB Model',
    'Airpod2'
]

out = {}
for item in lst:
    product, _, desc = item.partition('-')
    out[product] = desc
 
print(out)
# {'Macbook Air ': ' 13inch Model', 'Iphone13 ': ' Max Pro 65GB Model', 'Airpod2': ''}
```

---

You can also use a dictionary comprehension (or in this case a generator expression wrapped in `dict`, taking advantage of `dict`s constructor to turn tuples into key-value pairs.

```py
lst = [
    'Macbook Air - 13inch Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max Pro 65GB Model',
    'Airpod2'
]

out = dict(item.partition('-')[::2] for item in lst)
print(out)
# {'Macbook Air ': ' 13inch Model', 'Iphone13 ': ' Max Pro 65GB Model', 'Airpod2': ''}
```

Comment: It's great to use the `partition`.  But thought the OP want a dictionary at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, what you've shown in the last code block is a *list of dictionaries*. I'm assuming you want a dictionary that holds all devices as keys and descriptions as values. Please let me know if that's not what you're trying to do.

I would do a check on the format: Does the provided element have the format `'Device - Description'`? You can use a regex or use the way you've chosen. For the latter, you would need to check if `str(item).split('-')` returns a list with two elements, and if not, find a way to create an empty description.

Having done that, you can add the `device` and `description` to your dictionary by doing `new_lst[item] = description`. Problem so far: Your `new_lst` is no dictionary, but a list. So either initialize it by calling `dict()` or declare it like this: `new_lst = {}`

Comment: "a dictionary that holds all devices as keys and descriptions as values" yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yeah but your example is a list of dictionaries with just a single key so I wasn't sure.